# How do I use my earphones only as a microphone in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hardware

I recently got a new computer and I have CS:GO installed. Thing is, in order to play competitive you're basically required to have a microphone and I don't want to ask my parents because they just bought a £1000 computer.  However, I have some old earphones which have a perfectly good microphone but I want to hear the sound through my speakers which are built in. My earphones only have one output wire so I can't just not plug in the speaker one. I was asking here to see if there were some setting i could change in the console when I press "`" which would allow this to happen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about generic computer configuration, not gaming.

Comment: If so then could you point me to where I could ask this question?

Comment: perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)?  though I would word your question more towards how to use the headphone mic on the computer in general.  It may get closed if you leave the question as is since its specifically for a video game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computer may not support a 4 conductor jack (3 conductor is standard for audio; 4th conductor is newer for use in smartphones and such).

If that's the case, plugging it into the speakers wouldn't have made the mic work anyways.  Instead, you'd want to plug the headphones into the mic jack.

I'd like to point out that playing with your speakers instead of headphones isn't recommended.  It's harder to tell where sounds come from; people will swear quite a bit and if there are others in your house it may annoy them; and your teammates might hear themselves talking/annoying feedback on the mic coming back through your speakers.